# Application not in the App Store Search

Tags: itunes-store

When I search for my app by it's name 'Go Arc 2' I cannot find it in the App Store Search on iPad/iPhone.

I can find other apps that I've uploaded (we sell the app as a white label to different organization - we upload the same code but change the icon/splash and a short CFG file)

I clicked on any other app that I've uploaded (e.g. nilit)

Than I clicked `Developer Apps',

found the app that is missing in the search

sent my self a link

open the link in iPad/iPhone

And was able to install the app.

We recently had our apps removed because the `APPLE DEVELOPER PROGRAM` add expired, we paid and renew it yesterday.

This probably related to the app missing from search, but if so than how come the other apps appear in the search?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The App Store does perform a lot of caching, so you will probably have to wait up to 24 hours to see your apps back on the store and appearing in search results.  If all is not well by tomorrow night, you should probably contact Apple and have them look into it.